# Transparent background for List

Tags: ios, swiftui, background, cell, gradient

i Would like my TableView to become transparent in order to see the gradient background. I have tried with ListRowBackground but it doesn't work.Did I miss something ?
What if I want to put another gradient in my Tableview in addition to my background how should i proceed ? Thanks.
[image: Canvas]

struct test: View {

```
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    
                    List(iphonedata) { data in
                        CompleteCell(contact: data)
                }
            )
        }
        .navigationTitle("Version signées")

    }
}
```

}

Comment: "Translucide background for List"  What does 'Translucide' mean in English?  You mean, 'translucent'?

Comment: @El Tomato , transparent , without applying colors

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `List` **rows** clear. Do this by setting the [`listRowBackground(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/listrowbackground(_:)) to `Color.clear` so it is transparent.

```
List(iphonedata) { data in
    CompleteCell(contact: data)
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
}
```

*Note: this modifier doesn't work if you apply it to the `List`, it only works on the **rows** in the list.*

Comment: Unless `CompleteCell` is applying its own `background` somewhere, this works. Working example: `List([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], id: \.self) { data in Text(String(data)).listRowBackground(Color.clear) }`